# Keep getting "Deployment Id is not associated with current project." when publishing

Tags: gmail-addons

I'm trying to publish a Gmail Addon. I'm following guide here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish

but each time I click save in " Apps Marketplace SDK " configuration page I get the error in the title:

"Deployment Id is not associated with current project."

That's nonsense, since the associated project has been created directly with an action triggered from https://script.google.com

I have even tried to manually create a new project, and to associate the script to the new project, operation that succeeded but the save configuration fails at the same point with the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the HEAD deployment ID? If so then that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, it turned out the script was not properly linked to the google cloud project. You can find instructions on doing that here

https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/07/05/linking-cloud-platform-project-to-google-apps-script-project/